# 1-dimensional Point-Process in R (spatstat)

Tags: r, design-patterns, point, spatstat

I have asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738801/1-dimensional-point-process), which was closed as Too Broad. Now, I will try to specify.

Again, I would like to simulate a 1-dimensional point process in R. So far, I've only been working on 2-dimensional simulations and would need a bit of help.

My goal is a simulation like in the picture

[image: picture]

But, I only need the real line with the random points on it.

I use `spatstat` and have already found out that I can generate random points on a 1-dim Line with:

```
rpoisppOnLines(lambda, L, lmax = NULL, ..., nsim=1, drop=TRUE)
```

Now, I would like to produce the real line, preferably with matching labeling.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some crude code on getting samples from a point process.

```
library(spatstat)
lambda = 5
L = psp(0, 0, 3, 0, owin(c(0, 3), c(-1, 1)))
pp = rpoisppOnLines(lambda, L, lmax = NULL, nsim=1, drop=TRUE)
plot(pp$x, pp$y, pch = 4, lwd = 2, cex = 2)
abline(0, 0)
```

You could make your plot fancy with `ggplot2`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple linear network to represent the one dimensional line
segment you want to simulate on. This also makes it possible to fit models
(`lppm`), estimate the intensity non-parametrically (`density.lpp`), estimate
the K-function (`linearK`), and a bunch of other things:

```r
library(spatstat)
x_start <- 0
x_end <- 3
endpoints <- ppp(x=c(x_start, x_end), y=c(0,0), window = owin(c(x_start, x_end), c(-.1,.1)))
L <- linnet(endpoints, edges = matrix(c(1,2),ncol = 2))
X <- rpoislpp(lambda = 5, L = L)
```

However, this tool is designed for points on a complicated network and not
just the real line, so the plotting method is not really adapted to this
setting, and might not produce exactly what you want (too much white space):

```r
plot(X, pch = 4, lwd = 2, main = "")
axis(1)
```

[image]

You can extract the coordinates of the point pattern using `coords` and then
use the plotting method from the other answer from there:

```r
co <- coords(X)
co$x
#> [1] 1.3306861 2.5550691 1.7776248 2.9486675 1.8571362 2.5020587 1.4843001
#> [8] 0.4371669 0.8478670
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>